# USB LAN Adapter and Twisted Pair

Tags: usb, lan, twisted-pair

Can I use a USB to LAN adapter to make a Twisted Pair Cable Connection between tow PCs?

Answer (score 3):

*"USB to LAN adapter"* is a rather vague term.  A LAN could use one of many network technologies.  Note that the phrase "USB LAN" (as used in your title) could mean something different than using Ethernet adapters, e.g. [LAN over USB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB).

If you are referring to USB-to-Ethernet adapters and UTP or Cat 5/5e cables, then "yes", you could construct an *ad hoc* network.  If you use at least one high-quality USB-to-Ethernet adapter that supports auto MDI/MDI-X (aka "universal cable recognition"), then you can use an ordinary straight-through patch cable.  Otherwise you will need to use a crossover cable.

Note that the "B" in "USB" stand for "bus".  USB is a control and data bus just like PCI and PCI-Express.  A USB-to-Ethernet adapter should behave exactly like a PCI NIC or a NIC integrated into the motherboard.  The OS will conceal to the user the bus that the network interface is using.  Linux will assign a USB-to-Ethernet adapter an *ethN* device name just like any other NIC.

Answer (score 1):

You need an ethernet crossover cable.  If your PC doesn't have an ethernet port, use a usb network adapter and plug the crossover cable in to directly connect the two pc's without a hub/switch.